# Visual results for Maven tests in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, eclipse-plugin

I am building a web application with Spring. My IDE is Eclipse and my build tool is Maven. I have both unit and integration tests which I start with `mvn clean test` or `mvn clean verify`, respectively. When the tests are run this way in Eclipse the JUnit view does not show any results for the JUnit tests. Therefore, I have to inspect the console each time for Maven's text output. I find this necessity quite inconvenient and time-consuming.

Is there any plugin for Eclipse which shows the results in a graphical manner like the JUnit view usually does?

Comment: Why non running the unit tests from Eclipse? And usually integration tests is usally possible (depending on the IT's). Furthermore maven-surefire-plugin produces files in target/surefire-report which simply can be loaded into eclipse and show the results there...

Comment: Actually, the unit test running I would do like you suggest. However, I would prefer to have one single approach for both kinds of tests. Furthermore, the surefire reports are not the immediate visual feedback that I would like to experience...

Comment: Than run them in Eclipse instead from console. The integration tests could also be run from Eclipse (depending of the tests).

Comment: Just because I'm curious: Why do you run ITs in the `verify` phase rather than in `integration-test`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I do this in order to have Maven execute the post-integration-phase. This behavior is recommended on the [failsafe website](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: @khmarbaise I run everything in Eclipse. However, I use the maven plugin m2e to start a server before and shut it down after the tests. Hence, I see the results as a huge pile of text inside Eclipse.